# MyISAM with Innodb in the same Wordpress database reduce performace?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

My new Wordpress database all the Wordpress created tables use `InnoDB` engine and plugin created table use `MyISAM`. But older site database all the tables use `MyISAM` table engine. 
I use MySQL 5.5.35-cll i686.

If I use two different table engines in a same database, it will reduce my site performance or are there any downside?

Comment: What's the MySQL version?

Comment: The downside is that some of your tables are still in MyISAM.

Comment: @ Sparkot, i have update the post.

Comment: @ Bill, Thanks bill. You mean it's better go for InnoDB?

Comment: Yes, InnoDB supports ACID, data recovery, transactions, foreign keys, row-level locking -- none of which are supported by MyISAM. Also in modern versions of MySQL, InnoDB is faster and more scalable than MyISAM under most typical scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having InnoDB won't make MyISAM slower and vice versa. However you have to be more careful in memory allocation for InnoDB and MyISAM. Because they store data and indexes in different buffers.
MyISAM:

- Indexes in the [key buffer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-key-cache.html)
- Data in file system cache

InnoDB:

- Data and indexes (well, in InnoDB everything is indexes) in the [buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html)

So if you allocate more than necessary to InnoDB then MyISAM will have to access disk more often (and vice versa)

Comment: Thanks akuzminsky. So is it wise idea to convert rest of the tables to InnoDB engine?

Comment: Unless there is a very good reason for MyISAM (e.g. need for full text indexes etc) I tend to recommend InnoDB. It's been very actively developing and at the moment is much better than MyISAM from point of view of reliability, performance, flexibility in tuning. Even from data recovery standpoint(yes, unfortunately that happens too) chance to get your data back is way too bigger with InooDB than with MyISAM

Comment: Again thanks akuzminsky. I saw that some plugins display InnoDB fragmented. But when i try to optimize that table it's not success. Is it a normal?

Comment: well, I'm not sure what plugins you mean. I know you can check InnoDB tablespace fragmentation with XtraBackup (http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/analyzing_table_statistics.html?id=percona-xtrabackup:xtrabackup:statistics) . And yes, OPTIMIZE TABLE will rebuild a table, thus will defragment it. Not sure why it fails though.

Comment: I use wpxtram. I think it's better contact the developer. Again thank you so much.